# Updating specific cells based on another file

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two excel files and file A is the mother file and file B contains updates to some cells. What I want is to update file A with the updates in file B. Each line in the file has a reference number, that reference number is used to identify which line in file A should be updated.

Basically this is the manual process:

1. Copy the reference number in file B
2. find the copied reference in file A
3. go back to file B and copy the adjacent cell (three cells to the right)
4. paste the copied data in file A in the same cell (three cells to the right)
5. go back to file B and copy the next reference number
6. repeat step 2 - 5 until last line in file B

Comment: It sounds like you are going to want to use a VLOOKUP function, not necessarily vba. [This](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel-tips/how-to-use-excels-vlookup-function/1/) might help a bit. [Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your reference numbers are in column A and "three to the right" means column D -

into cell D2 of file a, enter (after adding your own path, filename and sheetname):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'C:\path\to\[file_b.xlsx]sheet_name'!$A$1:$D$1000,4,FALSE)
```

then copy D2 downwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but using VLOOKUP and copying it downwards would overwrite cells without updates. Lets say D2 down to D5 have updates then D6 does not then D7 down to D10 have updates. If i use VLOOKUP and copy it from D2-D10, D6 would return #NA. Now that seems to be okay but my actual file has approximately 5000 lines so it would generate more #NA cells. Also in this case Col D (the column which updates are put) is the only unprotected cell so all other columns cannot be edited. Again, thanks for your time.